# How to call clearInterval from a different function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I am trying to implement a stopwatch. When the start button is pressed setInterval is called. How can I stop by running clearInterval when the stop button is pressed, without having a global variable to pass as a parameter to clearInterval

```
  <body>
    <p class="clock">00:00:00</p>
    <button class='start'>Start</button>
    <button class="stop">Stop</button>
    <script>
      let totalMilliSeconds = 0;
      function tick(){
        totalMilliSeconds++;
          let hours = Math.floor(totalMilliSeconds/3600)
          let minutes = Math.floor(totalMilliSeconds/3600)
          let seconds = Math.floor(totalMilliSeconds/360)
          document.querySelector('.clock').textContent = `${hours}:${seconds}:${totalMilliSeconds}`
      }
      function start(){
        return setInterval(tick,1)
      }
      document.querySelector('.start').addEventListener('click',start)
      document.querySelector('.stop').addEventListener('click',start)
    </script>
    <p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `totalMilliSeconds` is a global variable so why not have the interval as a global?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're clearly going to need to store the reference to the interval *somewhere*. It's not clear what you mean by not having a global variable; one solution would be to declare it at the top:

```
  let totalMilliSeconds = 0;
  let interval = null;
  function tick(){
    totalMilliSeconds++;
      let hours = Math.floor(totalMilliSeconds/3600)
      let minutes = Math.floor(totalMilliSeconds/3600)
      let seconds = Math.floor(totalMilliSeconds/360)
      document.querySelector('.clock').textContent = `${hours}:${seconds}:${totalMilliSeconds}`
  }
  function start(){
    if (!interval) interval = setInterval(tick,1);
    return interval;
  }

  function stop() {
    if (interval) clearInterval(interval);
    interval = null;
  }
  document.querySelector('.start').addEventListener('click',start)
  document.querySelector('.stop').addEventListener('click',stop)
```

Thanks to JS scopes, the variable `interval` will be available in all functions declared in the script.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the Interval ID returned by `setInterval()`. In your case, you could do something like that:

```js
let intervalId;
document.querySelector('.start').addEventListener(
    'click',
    () => {intervalId = start();}
);
```

Then you can do `clearInterval(intervalId)` whenever you want.

Comment: `let` defines a block scoped local variable. Surely at the "root" scope it is still global @Kaiido? Local to global is still global?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid global variables you can wrap the whole thing in function declaration, then call it immediately. Any variables declared with `var` or `let` will only exist within the function's scope.

Example using Christoph's code sample:

```
(function() {

  let totalMilliSeconds = 0;
  let interval = null;

  function tick(){
    totalMilliSeconds++;
      let hours = Math.floor(totalMilliSeconds/3600)
      let minutes = Math.floor(totalMilliSeconds/3600)
      let seconds = Math.floor(totalMilliSeconds/360)
      document.querySelector('.clock').textContent = `${hours}:${seconds}:${totalMilliSeconds}`
  }

  function start(){
    if (!interval) interval = setInterval(tick,1);
    return interval;
  }

  function stop() {
    if (interval) clearInterval(interval);
    interval = null;
  }

  document.querySelector('.start').addEventListener('click',start)
  document.querySelector('.stop').addEventListener('click',stop)

})();
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures